# Is every trade in a decentralised exchange a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, decentralization, decentralized-exchange

Is every trade in a decentralised exchange a new smart contract? How does exchanging work in decentralised exchanges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the exchange, but I doubt a trade is a new contract in any dex (decentralized exchange).

A trade is typically a call to a certain function in a contract. That function executes the trade by calling some background contract functionality to calculate ratios and so on.

If you wish to trade token A for token B, the trade looks typically something like this:

1. You call token A's token contract and add *allowance* for the dex to withdraw some amount of token A from you
2. You call the dex to tell that you want to trade A for B
3. The dex withdraws token A from you (because you have given it allowance to do so) and returns you token B

Comment: Hey. I am wondering. When the dev withdraws token A from me, who pays the gas price for that transaction? Or is there no gas price?

Comment: Whoever issues the transaction, pays for it. So if person A withdraws token from somewhere, he issues a transaction for it, and since also pays for it.